# How follows the Strong Law of Large Numbers from Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, ergodic-theory

We want to prove the strong law of large numbers with Birkhoff's ergodic theorem.

Let $X_k$ be an i.i.d. sequence of $\mathcal{L}^1$ random variables. This is a stochastic process with measure-preserving operation $\theta$ (the shift operator). From Birkhoff's ergodic theorem, we obtain $\frac{X_0 + \dotsb + X_{n-1}}{n} \to Y$ a.s., with $Y=\mathbb{E}[X_1 \mid \mathcal{J}_{\theta}]$ a.s.

Now, if $Y$ constant a.s., $Y= \mathbb{E}[X_1]$ a.s., and we would have the desired result. **But why is $Y$ constant a.s.?**

Comment: $\theta$ is ergodic, so any $\theta$-invariant r.v. is a.s. constant.

Comment: Because the sigma-algebra $\mathcal J_\theta$ is trivial, in the sense that every $A$ in $\mathcal J_\theta$ has probability $0$ or $1$. Hence every random variable measurable for $\mathcal J_\theta$ is almost surely constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transformation $\theta$ on $\Omega^{\Bbb N}$ is ergodic. Indeed, it's enough to show that for each cylinder $A$ and $B$, we have 
$$\frac 1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\mu(\theta^{-k}A\cap B)\to \mu(A)\mu(B),$$
where $\mu$ is the measure on the product $\sigma$-algebra.
If $A=\prod_{j=0}^NA_j\times \Omega\times\dots$ and $B=\prod_{j=0}^NB_j\times \Omega\times\dots$, we have for $k>N$
\begin{align}
\theta^{-k}A\cap B&=\{(x_j)_{j\geq 0}, (x_{j+k})_{j\geq 0}\in A, (x_j)_{j\geq 0}\in B\}\\
&=\{(x_j)_{j\geq 0},x_{j+k}\in A_j, 0\leq j\leq N, x_j\in B_j,0\leq j\leq N\}\\
&=B_0\times \dots\times B_N\times \Omega\times\dots\times \Omega\times A_0\times\dots\times A_n\times \Omega\times\dots,
\end{align}
and we use the definition of product measure $\mu$ on cylinders (the $N$ first terms doesn't matter).

Since $\theta$ is ergodic, $\mathcal J_{\theta}$ consists only of events of measure $0$ or $1$. The conditional expectation with respect such a $\sigma$-algebra is necessarily constant.

Comment: A stationary process $X$ can be charakterized by the fact that $\theta$ is invariant with respect to the measure $\mathbb{P} \circ X$.. So this means that Birkhoff's ergodic theorem includes that any stationary process converges to something almost surely constant?

Comment: It means that the arithmetic means converge almost surely.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to ask if this not already implies that the arithmetic mean converges a.s. but also that it converges to a a.a. constant r.v.